# What is the span of the Fourier basis functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I heard a non-mathematician professor saying that "every function can be represented by sines and cosines".
I want it to be more precise.

Let the set
$$\{C_m:m=0,1,2,\cdots\}\cup\{S_n:n=1,2,\cdots\}$$
be the Fourier basis, where $C_m(t)=\cos mt$ and $S_n(t)=\sin nt$.
With the standard inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(t)\,dt$, the Fourier basis is orthogonal and thus is linearly dependent.

Question) What is the **span** of the Fourier basis?
More precisely, what does the set
$$\left\{f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\mid f=c_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nC_n+b_nS_n,\quad a_n\in\mathbb R,\: b_n\in\mathbb R\right\}$$
mean?

Surely, the above definition of the set, say, $\text{span}(\mathcal F)$, involves a limit of a function, and it requires a metric on the function space and I'm assuing the $\mathcal L^2$ space.
Does the Fourier basis span the whole $\mathcal L^2$ space?
(I think the [wikipedia document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Convergence_theorems) is stating it quite explicitly. And I want to know if it's right or not.)

Comment: Typically when talking about linear combinations we only consider adding _finitely_ many vectors. So the span is really the set
$$\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(a_kS_k+b_kC_k\right):a_k,b_k\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.$$
Obviously this isn't all of $\mathcal{L}^2$, but if we take the _closure_ of the span, then we do get all of $\mathcal{L}^2$. (In other words, the span is dense in $\mathcal{L}^2$, so its closure is the entire space.)

Comment: @csch2 So you talked about the closure of the span. You know, the notion of closure involves a metric(distance function) of a metric space, and I understand your metric is L2 distance right? Then, I think your answer is the same as my own answer. Thanks.